# I am getting TypeError: Failed to fetch while using this function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to make a full stack Transport management system with mern but it runs fine for 15s and after that TypeError: Failed to fetch comes in and it increases exponentially in my console.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const fetchBus = async () => {
 try{
 const response = await fetch("/api/buses");
 const json = await response.json();
 
 if (response.ok) {
 dispatch({ type: "SET_BUS", payload: json });
 }
 
 }
 catch(error){
 console.log(error)
 }
 };
 fetchBus(); 
 }, [handleOwnership,handleAvailable]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `fetch()` and `response.json()` both are **asynchronous tasks** and both returns a [Promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics).You need to parse json data inside an **if(response.ok){}** block:

**Replace:**

```
 useEffect(() => {

 const fetchBus = async () => {

 try{

   const response = await fetch("/api/buses");
   //const json = await response.json();//Not here
   
   if (response.ok) {
    const json = await response.json();//But Here
    dispatch({ type: "SET_BUS", payload: json });
   }
 
 }
 catch(error){
   console.log(error)
  }
 };

 fetchBus(); 
 }, [handleOwnership,handleAvailable]);
```

**Fetch JSON GET Request:**

```
let url = 'https://someurl.com';

let response = await fetch(url);
let responseOK = response && response.ok;
if (responseOK) {
    let data = await response.json();
    // do something with data
}
```

**Fetch JSON POST Request:**

```
let url = 'https://someurl.com';
let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                property_one: value_one,
                property_two: value_two
            })
        };
let response = await fetch(url, options);
let responseOK = response && response.ok;
if (responseOK) {
    let data = await response.json();
    // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was getting into a death-loop because I added functions in my dependencies but I learned that one should never do that instead of function add variables or arrays or primitives in dependencies.
For me I used use-state (variable) in dependencies instead of functions